# Can someone decompile my EXE file?

Tags: java, exe

I wanted to know if someone would be able to steal my source code from an EXE file made in JARSPLICE. I used Eclipse to create a JAR file (not runnable). Then I used JARSPLICE to create the EXE file. Is there any way anyone could decompile my EXE file and see even a bit of my source, if not all of it. Is there any way where I can protect my source for sure?

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably use something like `7Zip` to extract the resources of the executable

Comment: Generally, jar-to-exe converters make an exe which extracts the jar file(s) to a temporary folder. So when the program gets executed, the jar will be extracted somewhere on the hard drive; then your jar can be retrieved and decompiled.

Comment: Put `EXE` and I try to see if I can get Source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JARSPLICE, but Java bytecode is available through `javap -c`. In theory you could obfuscate it, but your (byte)code will always be recoverable in some format.